# LocationError on Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.DublinCoreViewlet for metatags

Tags: plone

I didn't change anything. I just rerun the ./bin/buildout -N and ./bin/instance fg. Then the error occurred. It happen to all my plone buidlout project. I check the Internet, fail to find the solution. Anyone came across this error?

```
 http://localhost:8080/Plone/front-page/document_view
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 240, in _exec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 180, in pt_render
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret    
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 531, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: file:/home/ivan/var/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.1.3-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/main_template.pt
   - Line 50, Column 8
   - Expression: <StringExpr u'plone.htmlhead'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'context': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fab678dfb10>,
       'here': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xa9a0628>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/Plone/front-page/document_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <FSPageTemplate at /Plone/front-page/document_view>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>}
  Module zope.contentprovider.tales, line 80, in __call__
  Module plone.app.viewletmanager.manager, line 85, in render
  Module plone.app.layout.viewlets.common, line 48, in render
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 819, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 682, in setRepeat
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /home/ivan/var/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.1.12-py2.6.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/dublin_core.pt
   - Line 1, Column 0
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/metatags'>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'context': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fab678dfb10>,
       'here': <ATDocument at /Plone/front-page>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0xa227e10>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/Plone/front-page/document_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x9c04090>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.DublinCoreViewlet object at 0xb12e850>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x8c6a310>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 97, in trustedBoboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 136, in traversePathElement
   - __traceback_info__: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.DublinCoreViewlet object at 0xb12e850>, 'metatags')
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 50, in traverse
   - __traceback_info__: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.DublinCoreViewlet object at 0xb12e850>, 'metatags', [])
LocationError: (<Products.Five.viewlet.metaconfigure.DublinCoreViewlet object at 0xb12e850>, 'metatags')
```

Comment: FWIW, I never run buildout -N. I make sure to pin all versions. Do you have dumppickedversions installed? Perhaps you installed some new version of something that is not compatible?

Comment: I do have dumppickedversions installed.

Answer (score 0):

We found why when wrong. I did change something. Ops! I accidentally edited the code in zope.viewlet package.